# how to passing data from statefulwidget to setState

Tags: flutter

I make a statefullwidget with final variable, like password.
But When I need to get data from extend statefullwidget to setstate it show error

```
class Inputtextfield extends StatefulWidget {
  const Inputtextfield({
    Key key, this.label, this.onChange, this.password = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String label;
  final Function onChange;
  final bool password;

  @override
  _InputtextfieldState createState() => _InputtextfieldState();
}

class _InputtextfieldState extends State<Inputtextfield> {
  
void _togglevisibility(){
    setState(() {
      widget.password =  !widget.password;
    });

}
```

i need to change it for Toggle, in setState Error say `password can't be setter,cause it final`, I try to fix error with `Ctrl + . -> Make 'password' Not Final` and error move to extend statefullWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`final` keyword prevents you to re-assign its value. It's better to keep the widget constructor variables immutable, and create a mutable variable into the `State` itself.
Therefore, to change your variable, you need to do as follows:

```
class _InputtextfieldState extends State<Inputtextfield> { 

    bool _password;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _password = widget.password;
    }

    void _togglevisibility(){ 
        setState(() { 
            // now, you can modify it
            _password = !_password; 
        }); 
    }
}
```

You can read more on this discussion: https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-dev/c/zRnFQU3iZZs/m/JX9ei27CBwAJ?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. `Final` variables can only be set `ONCE`. Once you set them they cannot be changed.

```
 final bool password = true; // this value cannot be changed again
```

In your case, if you want to update the value of `password`, you have to make it to be `Not Final` by removing the `final` keyword ie:

```
bool password = false;  // this can now be changed later using `setState()`
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make password not final.
2. Remove the "const" from the constructor